# Is there a menu bar tool which will let me eject external drives easily?

Tags: macos, mac, eject

I usually have a lot of external drives connected to my MacBook, such as flash drives, hard drives, and SD cards. It so happens that I need to eject them quite often.

The usual way I eject these is by either showing the desktop using a shortcut and dragging the drives I want to eject to the trash, or navigating to the finder and ejecting the drives from there, or by using a script which ejects all my external drives at once. However, when I want to do something simple like ejecting a flash drive or SD card (which I do quite often) I'd prefer not to break my workflow and simply be able to, say, click on a menu bar icon and select which volume I want to eject.

I haven't yet seen a utility which can achieve this. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: I find selecting the icon and Cmd+E works well : either for a single or multiple icons...

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm looking for something which does not require me to take an extra step to show my desktop/switch to another "space" and potentially disrupt my workflow (so a menu bar solution would be ideal)

Comment: No problem - only made the comment as when I use it sometimes some colleagues are so surprised!!!

Comment: No worries, it's very useful! Actually it's a much better method than dragging. I use ⌘E as a system-wide shortcut and I attempted to remap it with [Monomeeth's help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254842/is-there-a-way-to-set-another-shortcut-for-eject-in-the-finder-without-using-a). However, I just realized that with BetterTouchTool it's possible to use a wildcard, e.g. `Eject*` and assign that menu bar action to some other shortcut!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Semulov is in [maintainable mode](https://github.com/kainjow/Semulov/issues/47), there is a paid alternative that works good for me: [Jettison](https://www.stclairsoft.com/Jettison/)

Comment: It seems like this is the only app which is up to date and contains the features of all the older apps combined, so I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Try [Semulov](https://www.kainjow.com) - it is designed to eject volumes from the menu bar. The author has even made the [source available on GitHub](https://github.com/kainjow/Semulov).

Answer (score 4):

macOS included a built in menu bar item to eject removable drives. LifeWire has done a much better job than I could do providing instructions on how to add this to your Mac's menu bar.

Check it out here: [Add a Menu Bar Item to Eject a CD or DVD](https://www.lifewire.com/add-menu-bar-item-to-eject-cd-2260345)

**Update:** This answer is incorrect. While macOS includes an eject menu, it can only eject optical discs.

Comment: It's true that they do, but this is only for "ejecting CD or DVD drives" unfortunately. This would be a perfect solution, if only it supported external drives.

Comment: @SkeletonBow To my understanding this does support external drives. If that is not correct, I will remove this answer.

Comment: The article you liked does call it an "Eject CD/DVD menu item" and also states that it is used to "eject or insert a CD or DVD." I additionally can't see any external drives when I click on it :P

Comment: Oh, and you should keep this answer as it answers part of the question. Someone may find it useful

Comment: @SkeletonBow I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try Mountain. http://appgineers.de/mountain/
Not only does it allow you to mount and eject drives, you can select to not mount a drive on restart. I unmount a drive after cloning and don't want it mounted again on restart. This app does exactly what I want.

Comment: Look like it hasn't been updated in four years at this point

Answer (score 2):

The Finder eject shortcut is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, e for eject, easy!

This also works on the desktop. Click/select the drive, mash <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, give it a couple seconds to disappear, done!

Note that this also works if you have a Finder window open to any folder on an external drive, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and it will eject that drive.

If it’s a multi-partition drive, add Shift to eject the whole disk device rather than just the single partition.

Answer (score 1):

Elgato makes a [dock eject utility](https://www.elgato.com/en/dock/thunderbolt-3) for their Thunderbolt dock, which really only makes sense in context to disks. I don’t know if it’s somehow exclusive to use with their dock, but worth a look for a quick access eject utility.