# Run an AppleScript daily with launchd

Tags: applescript, launchd

I'm trying to run an AppleScript which ejects all drives (from the excellent answer by Monomeeth [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255009/197118)) daily at 8 am using `launchd`. After some searching, I decided the best way to do this was by using `launchd`. However, I'm running into an error.

The `.plist` which I have in my user `LaunchAgents` directory is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
  <key>Label</key> 
  <string>local.SkeletonBow.EjectAllDrivesAt8</string> 
  <key>Program</key> 
  <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string> 
  <key>ProgramArguments</key> 
  <array> 
    <string>/usr/local/etc/Daily\ Scripts/Eject\ All.scpt</string>
  </array> 
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>08</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>00</integer>
  </dict>
</dict> 
</plist>
```

The AppleScript in question, `Eject All.scpt`, runs fine when I run it with `osascript Eject\ All.scpt` in my `zsh` shell.

According to [this site](https://www.maketecheasier.com/use-launchd-run-scripts-on-schedule-macos/), I should "load the job" into `launchctl`. I did this by running, according to their instructions, the following:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.SkeletonBow.EjectAllDrivesAt8.plist
```

And then tried to test it by running

```
launchctl start local.SkeletonBow.EjectAllDrivesAt8.plist
```

However, this particular action causes a cross to be shown in the Terminal, implying that something wrong has happened. I'm guessing that it's due to the syntax in my `.plist` file.

Answer (score 1):

One shouldn't include the `.plist` extension when starting a launchtl process directly. Your command should read, instead, `launchctl start local.SkeletonBow.EjectAllDrivesAt8`

Also, the `launchctl` man pages indicate one shouldn't use leading zeroes when setting Calendar start time. The content should be `<integer>8</integer>` and `<integer>0</integer>` for the `Hour` and `Minute` keys.

Keep in mind, too, that when using *CalendarInterval* (as opposed to an elapsed-time *Interval*) to set a launch time for a process, that if the machine should unexpectedly be asleep at 8:00AM and therefore be unable to initiate the process, it *will* initiate the process upon awakening. That does not happen when the time setting is interval based.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this part is the problem:

```
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/etc/Daily\ Scripts/Eject\ All.scpt</string>
  </array>
```

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) doesn't mention a `Program` item. When I tested it, it seemed to be ignored. Something like this worked for me:

```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <string>/usr/local/etc/Daily\ Scripts/Eject\ All.scpt</string>
  </array>
```

It's a bit surprising that *all* parts have to go in the `ProgramArguments` array. The first one really is the program, isn't it, Apple? Eh bien, c'est la vie....

You can also shorten the code a bit:

```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>osascript</string>
    <string>/usr/local/etc/Daily\ Scripts/Eject\ All.scpt</string>
  </array>
```

(I guess `launchd` / `launchctl` looks at the `PATH` to find `osascript`.)

Comment: `<key>Program</key>` is perfectly fine. `<key>ProgramArguments</key>` is primarily for the argument of the `program` been executed, but there is an exception too. Have a look at the manual page for `launchd.plist`.  See in particular, **Program <string>** and **ProgramArguments <array of strings>**. You can read the _manual page_ for `command ` in **Terminal** by typing `command` and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**.

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be any _backslash_ escaping spaces, just, e.g. `<string>/usr/local/etc/Daily Scripts/Eject All.scpt</string>`